# Exclude directory from module distribution

Tags: go

I have the following directory structure for my module:

```
- go.mod
- go.sum
- names.go
- internal
  - namesreader
    - namesreader_test.go
    - namesreader.go
- testdata
  - 0-names.txt.gz
  - 100-names.txt.gz
  - 10m-names.txt.gz
```

I want to exclude the `./testdata/` directory from distribution so that my module installs faster but I can find any documentation on how to do that.

Comment: You cannot. Like you cannot remove the tests.